# Reactjs Map through array of base64 images only renders last item in array

Tags: reactjs

In my mongodb i have documents that contain arrays called **stackUsed**, the **stackUsed** arrays contain images converted to  **base64**. I want to display the base64(images) but it only renders the last item from the array for every document. I attached a picture for 1 of the stackUsed arrays. [image]

this image is a image of the mongodb documents
[image]

This is my jsx for rendering the array but it only renders the last image in the array

```
   <ul>
    {stackUsed.map((image, key) => {
      return (
        <li key={key} className="stackUsedimgList">
          <img
             // what should i set src to?
            src={image}
            alt="icon corresponding programming language used."
            className="stackUsedImg"
          />
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
```

Comment: It should work. If it's rendering one image only then there is a possibility that the other images were not properly encoded.

Comment: Can you post the base64 string of the images that didn't work here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: it only renders the last image, ( i removed image at index(2) and now it instead renders the image at index(1) so i guess they are all properly encoded since i can display them if they are the last in array. I also got rid of the error i had for 1 of the documents.

Comment: I found the error.  For my Li class **stackUsedimgList** i had set **position:Absolute** so all my images was stacking on top of eachother.